# BigQuery Job State stuck in "RUNNING"

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a batch process that does a json job load usually once per hour. My process checks to see if there's a previous job still pending or running before it continues. It's not uncommon for jobs to be in PENDING state for some time before completing, I  have seen upwards of an hour to a few hours.

In this case I have a job that has been in "RUNNING" state for about 4 hours now, I've never seen it quite this long. I have checked other posts here to see if anyone else had the issue and I did find one chap who's job took about 4 hours to complete.

My job ID for the job in question is: #job_Canl6-TBi4F6sWDOjB6ng7PxoZA. I know about why jobs can be stuck in PENDING states due to queue times, but I was not aware this was the case in the RUNNING state too - can anyone confirm in their experience that this is not abnormal? In my experience (I have been running this process for over a year) it is and can anyone confirm this is not a current back-end issue with BigQuery?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The BigQuery load & extract pipeline is backed up. We're currently investigating with the Google Cloud Storage on-call folks.

Comment: Got it - missed this comment before I closed - thanks for the update!

Comment: @JordanTigani not sure if this is helpful but my next job attempt ended with the following error results:

`[reason] => notFound

[message] => Not found: Google Storage File gs://reztrack/batch_1404858850.json`

Comment: For those who are wondering, there still appear to be issues but Google is still looking into it.

Comment: Please use BigQuery's public issue tracker to report bugs or service disruptions, and reserve StackOverflow for more general questions about BigQuery usage. http://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list

Answer (score 4):

This issue should be resolved now. See comments #9 and #10 here:

http://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=103

In the future, I'd recommend filing a bug via BigQuery's public issue tracker to notify us of bugs or other issues with the service. Your issue will likely get more prompt attention from the team that way. Also, StackOverflow is more appropriate for questions about BigQuery usage that will be relevant long-term; I suspect the moderators would prefer we not use StackOverflow as a bug tracker.

The public issue tracker is here:

https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list

Thanks, and apologies for the trouble today!

Comment: Completely understand the difference now - thank you for explaining. Will use the public issue tracker from now on to report bugs and problems, thanks again.